# Mysql - If there are duplicates in table, select the oldest one according to date_created column

Tags: mysql

I have table which stores lecturers' available dates for lectures. Structure goes something like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lecturer_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| kraj_id      | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| okres_id     | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lecture_date | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_created | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There can be rows with duplicate `lecture_date`.
When this happens I need to select the oldest row according to `date_created`. Have not solved it yet.

**EDIT:**

sample data:

```
+----+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | lecturer_id | kraj_id | okres_id                                          | lecture_date        | date_created        |
+----+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 36 |          38 | 1,4,12  | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,18,19,20,21,22,72,73,74,75,76,77,78 | 2017-12-29 00:00:00 | 2017-12-16 16:20:38 |
| 37 |          38 | 1,4,12  | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,18,19,20,21,22,72,73,74,75,76,77,78 | 2017-12-30 00:00:00 | 2017-12-16 16:20:40 |
| 38 |          38 | 1,4,12  | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,18,19,20,21,22,72,73,74,75,76,77,78 | 2017-12-31 00:00:00 | 2017-12-16 16:20:42 |
| 39 |          41 | 7,12    | 33,34,35,36,37,72,73,74,75,76,77,78               | 2017-12-29 00:00:00 | 2017-12-16 16:21:15 |
| 40 |          41 | 7,12    | 33,34,35,36,37,72,73,74,75,76,77,78               | 2017-12-30 00:00:00 | 2017-12-16 16:21:17 |
| 41 |          41 | 7,12    | 33,34,35,36,37,72,73,74,75,76,77,78               | 2017-12-31 00:00:00 | 2017-12-16 16:21:20 |
+----+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

`kraj_id` and `okres_id` are ids of regions which are covered by lecturer. I am selecting rows by `lecturer_id` (for example: WHERE lecturer_id IN (38, 41)). If two or more lecturers cover the same regions there is chance that there will be duplicity in `lecture_date`. In that case I need to select the oldest according to `date_created`. In above example that would mean selecting rows with id 36, 37, 38.

Comment: example data? And besides are many  max-per-group answers hier on Stackoverflow.. . https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+max+per+group or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgreatest-n-per-group%5D+mysql

Comment: @RaymondNijland Hi, I edited my question, added some sample data. I tried some magic with HAVING clause but it did not work out. I suspect using subqueries will be needed. I am not sure how these work.

Comment: Would something like ORDER BY date_created ASC LIMIT 1 be helpful?

Comment: @tbedner Hi, thanks for suggestion. I tried it out but it returns only one row. Below you can find solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745679/8858190) and it worked for me.

I had to make some changes to the query and this is the final version:

```
SELECT
  id,
  lecture_date,
  lecturer_id,
  date_created 
FROM lecturer_has_dates
WHERE date_created IN (
  SELECT MIN(date_created)
  FROM lecturer_has_dates
  GROUP BY lecture_date
)
AND lecture_date >= NOW()
AND lecturer_id IN (38, 41)
ORDER BY lecture_date DESC;
```

Thanks for all your suggestions!